# Straight lines with an edge detection algorithm

Tags: image-processing, noise, edge-detection

I've been thinking of an algorithm for object recognition but it would relies heavily on straight non-noisy lines and as far as I know this is hard to obtain with edge detection algorithms. What's the best edge detection algorithm to obtain lines as straight as possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [**Hough transform**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) or one of it's extensions.

The simplest version of this transform is linear and appropriate for detecting straight lines.

In the transformed space (*Hough space*), angles and distances are found as points where curves intersect.

Libraries for calculating the Hough transform exist in

- C++ - [OpenCV](http://www.opencv.org) (Has Python bindings)
- Matlab - [`hough` in the image processing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/hough.html)
- Python - [Scikits-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html)

**Related Questions and Answers**

See this previous answer for more [help on understanding the Hough transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/help-understanding-hough-transform).

Comment: Just one addition concerning libs: latest version of OpenCV not just has C++ bindings, but uses C++ classes in its core. Also consider using [new OpenCV website](opencv.org) for references.

Comment: @ffriend: Cheers, updated answer

Comment: The scikit-image link is out of date. Here is the example I think you mean to reference: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use LSD line detector http://www.ipol.im/pub/algo/gjmr_line_segment_detector/