# Resources for learning image processing

Tags: image-processing

I just started learning about image processing. I am using the book "Digital image processing" by Gonzalez and Woods but I don't like this book very much. I would like to read a book which can actually make me interested in image processing.

Can you suggest some good resources?

Comment: To all the close votes: while I agree that it's a difficult question, we had another [similar _successful_ question on the site already](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2753/resources-for-an-introduction-to-computer-vision/2826#2826), it's just about computer vision. To the OP: check if your question might be answered there. Also, I think Gonzales&Woods is a good book. Maybe you should be interested in image processing first, and then go learn it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to read a book? As a good resource to start, I'd suggest playing around with the [scikit-image library](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/). Trying the classical algorithms with real-world images will give you a nice feel of how difficult & amusing image processing is.

Refer to a book afterwards, when you want to have a grasp of the maths behind the algorithm.

You can also try O'Reilly's ["Programming Computer Vision with Python"](http://programmingcomputervision.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Gonzales&Woods is a good book.

since u need some other book for reference i may suggest 
 
Author: S. Jayaraman, S. Esakkirajan And T. Veerakumar
 
Title of the Book: Digital Image Processing
 
Publisher: Tata McGraw - Hill Education Pvt. Ltd, New Delhi
 
Year: 2010
 
Edition: 3

This is also good book for beginners